# How to only select year in DateTimeType Forms Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime, symfony4

So I have this code in my FormType

```
    $builder
->add('anio', DateTimeType::class, [
                    'widget' => 'choice',
                    //'years' => range(date('Y')-1, date('Y')+1),
                    'format' => 'yyyy'
    
                ])
```

And I would like to just show just a year selector and not the whole time m-d-Y h-m.

Is this possible?
Ty!

Answer (score 1):

Following this documentation from Symfony docs :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#input-format

You need to do this :

```
->add('anio', DateTimeType::class, [
     'input_format' => 'Y',    
])
```